# Adaptar texto al ancho de una imagen con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando un script en PHP, para escribir arriba de unas imagenes, lo que necesito es que el texto que ingrese el usuario ocupe el 100% del ancho de la imagen, he intentando con algo como esto:

```
$tam_fuente=floor($width/$cant_caracteres);
```

Donde $width es el ancho (en pixeles) de la imagen y $cant_caracteres, es la cantidad de caracteres que escribio el usuario, lo obtengo con strlen(). Pero el resultado no logra lo que busco. ¿Es posible hacer lo que quiero?. Gracias

He logrado hacerlo con un bucle, no me parece lo mas optimo pero me quedo de esta manera:

```
$tam_texto=imagettfbbox (12,0,$fuente,$string);
for($i=13;$tam_texto[2]<=$width && $i<$height;$i++)
{
    $tam_texto=imagettfbbox ($i,0,$fuente,$string);
    if($tam_texto[2]<$width)
    {       
        $tam_fuente=$i;             
    }   

}
```

Comment: pero si width es 100.. y tienes 1 caracter.. entonces el tamaño de la fuente es 100.. pero no de ancho.. de tamaño...

Comment: _lo que necesito es que el texto que ingrese el usuario ocupe el 100% del ancho de la imagen_  ¿En qué sentido y cómo? Por ejemplo, ¿que se autojustifique según el ancho de la imagen? ¿Que el elemento donde está dicho texto (`<p>, <div>, <span>`)  u otro ocupe el 100%? ¿En tamaño de fuente? ¿...? ¿...? Especifica.

Comment: Estimados, muchas gracias por su ayuda, estoy trabajando con la libreria GD, no estoy utilizando html ni css, es un script para imprimir sobre la imagen, no se si me explico, he logrado un avance que agrego a la pregunta. Gracias!